# What's the solution to this kind of shadow acne?

Tags: glsl, lighting, opengl-es, shadows, shadow-mapping

I'm working with a OpenGL ES/GLSL homebrew engine my company developed, in C++. Below is a screenshot of it rendering shadow acne. The light's direction is too perpendicular to the face of the curve there-- the area with the stripes is only like 3 pixels wide on the shadow texture.

What's the best solution to this issue?  All I can think of is rendering the light from slightly different directions, but then I'm unsure how to mix the two shadows in the area in question.

[image: shadow acne]

Edit: The dot-bias solution didn't work.  Filtering the shadow texture a tiny bit (9 adjacents) helps enough to make it usable in the final product.  At some point (but not right now) I might trying rendering an additional shadow texture from a slightly different light position and blend the two, in an attempt to get more pixels into that bend on the shadow texture.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. What are you rendering with?

Comment: @Pikalek Oh, sorry... it's OpenGL ES/GLSL,using a homebrew engine my company developed, in C++.

Comment: I've edited to include that information directly in the question & the tags - feel free to tweak the edit (especially if that tag should have been `opengl-es2`). Usually the first thing to try is adding a small bias (as discussed [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/166614/33287) & [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58761796/950488)).

Comment: @Pikalek, thanks for the edit.  I've tried various levels of bias, but am caught between peter-panning and acne.  Though you've given me an idea, and I might try adjusting the bias based on the face's normal dot the light.

Comment: You're welcome. It's good to include info about what you've tried; it give clues that will lead to a solution & reduces answers covering things that did work. If bias the dot normal works, post what you did as an answer. If it doesn't edit to include the outcome.

Comment: And if you haven't already done so, skim the shadow acne posts on [GDSE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=shadow%20acne), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=shadow%20acne) & [CGSE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/search?q=shadow+acne).

Comment: did you try render frontface versus render backface